# Python: How to add a prefix to tags in an xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml

I use the python asciimathml library to parse some asciimathml and convert it to MathML

```
>>> from xml.etree.ElementTree import tostring
>>> tostring(asciimathml.parse('sqrt 2'))
'<math><mstyle><msqrt><mn>2</mn></msqrt></mstyle></math>'
```

The only trouble is I need my tags with a `m:` prefix. How do I change above code so I get:

```
'<m:math><m:mstyle><m:msqrt><m:mn>2</m:mn></m:msqrt></m:mstyle></m:math>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename the tag, adding the 'm:' prefix:

```
import asciimathml
from xml.etree.ElementTree import tostring

tree = asciimathml.parse('sqrt 2')
for elem in tree.getiterator():
    elem.tag = 'm:' + elem.tag

print tostring(tree)
```

Result:

```
<m:math><m:mstyle><m:msqrt><m:mn>2</m:mn></m:msqrt></m:mstyle></m:math>
```